# Replace a element instead another element by jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want replace a(or each) element(number) instead another element(number) in a class while running page.

I try as following code but doesn't word true, what do i do?

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/yMnDt/

```
<div class="myGrid">
    1
    <p>
    123145
</div>​

$(".myGrid").clone().find('1').replaceWith( "8" );
```

​

Comment: where is the end tag of `<p>`?

Comment: If I remember correctly (correct me if wrong) the endtag for `p` isn't needed. It is cleaner though.

Comment: It's bad practice to never put any endtags even though they sometimes aren't necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want? [http://jsfiddle.net/yMnDt/7](http://jsfiddle.net/yMnDt/7/)

Comment: Yes, i want this, but how can done replaceWith() in body without alert?

Comment: changed it, see if this is what you want

Comment: You can replace several elements together? Like: `8 -replaceWith-> 1` & `9 -replaceWith-> 2` & `10 -replaceWith-> 3` & `20 -replaceWith-> 2` and ... . How is it?

Answer (score 1):

If you want replace ONLY number 1 with 8 You need to do the follwing change

> - you need to put "1" in span tag

please check the Below link

http://jsfiddle.net/8nrS2/1/

Comment: You can replace several elements together? Like: `8 -replaceWith-> 1` & `9 -replaceWith-> 2` & `10 -replaceWith-> 3` & `20 -replaceWith-> 2` and ... . How is it?

Comment: yes you can replace any element with this.
SPAN tag is for just getting the data Elem and The data just replace with you what you want.

Comment: Please check the above link 
IF you dont want to write the invidual code you can write a each function for this

Answer (score 0):

This uses replaceWith and no alert in the body
http://jsfiddle.net/T2GAZ/